# JSON manipulations in Spring boot & Angular

Tags: json, spring-boot, angular5

I'm using Spring Bootand querying a MySQL db, using the following code

```
@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public String Date() {  
Connection conn = null;
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfDates = null;
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Connecting to database...To retrive DATE");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

String countQuery= "SELECT migrations.mignum, migration_states.statemigrations.projectleader, migrations.productiondate," 
+ " migrations.installationtiers, migrations.targetplatform, migrations.apprelated, migrations.appversion FROM migrations, migration_states WHERE migrations.productiondate='2018-07-07"; 
QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
listOfDates = queryRunner.query(conn, countQuery, new MapListHandler());

conn.close();
}
catch (SQLException  se) {
se.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
//Handle errors for Class.forName
e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
}
return new Gson().toJson(listOfDates);
}
```

which will return me a JSon object like below

```
[
{"state":"Approval in Staging","mignum":146384,"projectleader":"James Rice","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Content Only","appversion":""},
{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146451,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"UPS Pickup Point Attribute Injector","appversion":"18.7.1"},
{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146453,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"UPS Pickup Point DB Web Services","appversion":"18.7.1"},
{"state":"Migration to Mahwah","mignum":146485,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Account Invoice Authorization","appversion":"18.07.01"},
{"state":"Migration to Mahwah","mignum":146487,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"My Choice Enrollment Component","appversion":"18.07.03"},
{"state":"Migration to Mahwah","mignum":146489,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"My Choice Enrollment WebApp","appversion":"18.07.01"},
{"state":"Migration to Mahwah","mignum":146492,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL81","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"LASSO","appversion":"UTA_18.07.03"},{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146495,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"LASSO","appversion":"18.07.03"},{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146496,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"LASSO","appversion":"18.07.03"},{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146497,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Precommissioning Authorization ","appversion":"18.07.09"},{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146498,"projectleader":"Keith Lucas","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Precommissioning Authorization ","appversion":"18.07.06"},{"state":"Approval by Dev Staging","mignum":146547,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Account Validation Component ","appversion":""},{"state":"Migration to Mahwah","mignum":146549,"projectleader":"Amardeep Grewal","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"URL Alias","appversion":""},{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146565,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Quantum View SubServer","appversion":"9.3.0"},
{"state":"Approval by Dev Staging","mignum":146566,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Web Email Preference App","appversion":"v3.8.19"},
{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146569,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"View Bill","appversion":"4.0.2"},
{"state":"Migration to Mahwah","mignum":146578,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Claims History Component","appversion":"NA"},
{"state":"Approval by QA in Staging","mignum":146579,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Address Search Component ","appversion":"2.1.0"},
{"state":"Approval by Dev Staging","mignum":146581,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"DCOWS","appversion":" 8.03.01"},
....
]
```

Can anyone let me know,how to perform the following manipulations in Spring side or Angular side

1. Find the count of each state so that I get Json array as follows

   [
   {"state":"Approval by Dev Staging", "count": 12},
   {"state":"Approval by QA in Staging", "count": 12},
   ...
   ]
2. Get the data present for each state Eg:

if state = "Approval by Dev Staging"
     get its details as json object to display in front-end Angular
if state = "Approval by QA in Staging"
     get its details as json object to display in front-end Angular
Eg:

```
[{
"name":"Approval by QA in Staging",
"value":[
{"mignum":146547,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Account Validation Component ","appversion":"xxx"},
{"mignum":146547,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Account Validation Component ","appversion":"xxx"},
....
}]
},
{
"name":"Migrations to Staging",
"value":[{
{"mignum":146547,
"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jul 7, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Account Validation Component ","appversion":"xxx"} ....
}]
```

}]

.... etc

Comment: where do you get the json object from? is it coming through some http api, or is it in a file, or a literal string? database?

Comment: It will be coming from query to MYSQL
"SELECT migrations.mignum, migration_states.state AS Current_State FROM migrations, migration_states WHERE ((migrations.productiondate=(SELECT valval FROM global_configs WHERE valname='erday')))"

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, I was able to acheive it in Angular side using the following code
in *dashboard.service.ts* by calling as below

```
    getDateDashboard() {
        return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/dashboard', this.options).pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
     }

in *dashboard.component.ts*  by making a call to above service as follows  

        for (let index = 0; index < chartdataa.length; index++) {

                  if(chartdataa[index].state=="Approval by Dev. in Mahwah"){
                    this.displayDevMawah.data = chartdataa.filter(function(data:any){ return data.state == "Approval by Dev. in Mahwah";});

                    this.displayDevMawah.count = this.displayDevMawah.data.length;
                   console.log("this.displayDevMawah.count-->", this.displayDevMawah.count);

                  }

                  if(chartdataa[index].state=="Approval by Dev. in Windward"){
                    this.displayDevWindward.data = chartdataa.filter(function(data:any){ return data.state == "Approval by Dev. in Windward";});

                    this.displayDevWindward.count = this.displayDevWindward.data.length;
                   console.log("this.displayDevWindward.count-->", this.displayDevWindward.count);
    }
  ...   
}
```

Now I need help to get json data for my first question from the above result, which is
***Getting the json data with state and count for each state in Angular side/ Spring side as follows***

```
[
{"state":"Completed","count":240},
{"state":"Pending Approval by Development in Windward","count":2},
{"state":"Pending Approval by QA in Windward","count":1},
{"state":"Pending Migration to Mahwah","count":1},
{"state":"Pending Migration to Production","count":3},
...
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String url(@RequestBody String jsonData) {

        String messageId="0";       
        try {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Message ms = new Message(); //write your class name that uses database entities

            Message message = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Message.class);


                if (message != null) {

                    String text= message.getMessage();

                    messageRepository.save(ms);//enter reposistory that use in controller

                    ms.getMessageId().toString();
                }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String errorMsg = ex.getMessage();
            if(errorMsg!="")
            return messageId + " donot save Error ";
        }
        return messageId;

    }
```

Comment: Got the json object only  
`@GetMapping("/dashboard")
 public String Date() { 
  Connection conn = null;
  List<Map<String, Object>> listOfDates = null;
  String countQuery= "SELECT migrations.mignum, migration_states.state FROM migrations, migration_states WHERE migrations.productiondate='2018-07-07"; 
    QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
             listOfDates = queryRunner.query(conn, countQuery, new MapListHandler());    
    conn.close();
        return new Gson().toJson(listOfDates);
 }`  


want 2 display 
1. Count by each state  
2. Get all data w.r.t state

Comment: Please format the code properly and describe what tge code is doing. And check `if(errorMsg!="")`

Comment: @Marged I added the code to the question for clarity

Comment: Thanks this is only spring side code. in angularJS or javascript you can call it with loop for multiple inserts.